# Function is not working in table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I created a function that will return a varchar

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Test
(
    @i INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @it VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @it = 'INSERT INTO @Test
                VALUES (1)
    '

    RETURN @it

END
```

I tried to used that function in the query below but got an error.

```
DECLARE @d VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    i INT
)

SET @d = dbo.Test(1)

SELECT @d

EXEC (@d)

SELECT * FROM @Test
```

Why function is not working in table variable?

How to make it work?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Must declare the table variable "@Test"

Comment: That's obvious right? cause, table variable @Test is not present in the scope of function definition.

Comment: I tried to put that in the function but still not working

Comment: variables declared outside the scope of dynamic sql are not available in the dynamic sql

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? It is very unclear. Functions cannot do dynamic SQL nor DML. And your function just returns a piece of text and doesn't do anything to it so the function isn't needed anyway. You aren't going to get any helpful answers until you make it clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
If we try to use Select from @test from outside its declaration scope then it will not work. Hence, it has been SET in @it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Test]
(
    @i INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @it VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @it = 'DECLARE @Test TABLE(i INT); INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1); SELECT * FROM @Test'

    RETURN @it

END

DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    i INT
)

DECLARE @d VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @d = dbo.Test(1)

SELECT @d

INSERT INTO @Test
EXEC (@d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way by using a temporary table instead of table variable since table variable won't be accessible as already pointed by others in comment. [Not Tested]

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Test
(
    @i INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @it VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @it = 'CREATE TABLE #Test(i INT); INSERT INTO #Test
                VALUES (1)'

    RETURN @it

END
```

Then call your function like

```
DECLARE @d VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @d = dbo.Test(1)

SELECT @d

EXEC (@d)

SELECT * FROM #Test
```

Comment: Wouldn't work. Variables declared in the scope of dynamic SQL are not available outside the scope

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL executes in a separate context, in which your variables (including table ones) are unavailable.

The nearest thing to what you are trying to do is, probably, this:

```
insert into @Test
exec(@d);
```

whereas function will return only the `select` part.

Don't forget, though, that in Microsoft SQL Server you cannot nest `insert into ... exec` statements.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have a function that builds one or more insert statements that can then be executed to populate a table, that cannot work using a Table Variable as those are not available in other scopes (i.e. sub-process or parent-process scopes). The only way to do something like this is:

1. Use a local temporary table (i.e. `#Temp`)
2. The function can return a string that has insert statements that insert into the local temp table.
3. The local temp table needs to be created before the string with the INSERT statements is executed.
4. Then you can execute the string. Because the temp table already exists, it can be accessed by a sub-process (i.e. the `EXEC`).

Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Test
(
    @i INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @it VARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @it = 'INSERT INTO #Test (Col1)
                VALUES (' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @i) + ');
    '

    RETURN @it;
END;
```

And use in this manner:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

--DROP TABLE #Test;
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    Col1 INT
);

SET @SQL = dbo.Test(1);
SET @SQL += dbo.Test(55);

SELECT @SQL;

EXEC (@SQL);

SELECT * FROM #Test;
```